# Chrome developer tools > user-agent stylesheet overrides <strong>, <b> rules

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I'm working on developing a site for a client. When working on my CSS in Chrome Developer Tools, it shows:

user agent stylesheet

strong, b {

<strike>font-weight: bolder;</strike>

}

The user agent stylesheet is disabling the bold on strong and b elements. What is this? How do I turn it off? Everything shows up correctly in Firefox. Why is it trying to alter the way I am styling things?

Comment: Does your page show correctly in Chrome, like it does in Firefox?

Comment: Show correctly? Yes everything except for <strong> elements. They are don't show up bold because of the above reason...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When I add this style to a page:

```
<style>
strong {
    font-weight: normal;
}
</style>
```

The text looks not bold and the inspector shows:

[image]:

Meaning user agent style was overridden with provided value.

Is it what you are seeing? If yes then everything works as expected. If not then maybe your style rules for `strong` elements are not correct so they are not executing? Can you show your css?

Comment: Hmmm weird. I will look at my problem again and get back to you. I'm not sure why it's not working.